# Getting the request headers send via file_get_contents()

Tags: php

When using `file_get_contents()` to request an external URL, how can I find out what headers I've sent, or alternatively what headers I am about to send? I'm basically looking for a request counterpart for `$http_response_header` or anything else I can use to extract the same data.

I know I get to set headers myself with `stream_context_create(array ('http' => array ('header' => $header)))`, but I want to see what headers are actually being sent in the end, including default ones.

Comment: You may want to use cURL ;)

Comment: When I was actually using cURL there have been situations where the people in the #php channel told me to switch to `file_get_contents()`.
I would like to have problems solved now instead of being thrown back and forth between libraries.

Comment: An answer has been posted, but since it has been deleted. Responding to the comment that proposed I already have all the request data at hand as I am the one setting them:

I am assuming there are some default headers being sent as well that is not known to me.

Comment: Make the same request to an URL of your own, and simply dump the request headers received in that script …?

Comment: What if PHP doesn't send the exact same headers for different URLs? What if I want to send in a bug report for an API where I want to provide the exact headers sent that resulted in the unexpected response headers and content I got?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a consistent header to go out with each `file_get_contents` request, use the stream contexts like this example:

```
<?php

// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);

?>
```

Src: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

---

If you want to see what headers you are sending, the best option I can think of involves `curl` (not file_get_contents), which looks like this:

When making the request; set this option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
```

Then you can debug the request and see what headers were sent using this (after the request was sent):

```
var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
```

More info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

Comment: does not address the question per se. "I want to see what headers are actually being sent"